# Gitlab pages - Incremental deploy

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-pages

In gitlab pages, public directory content seems to be cleaned at each deployment. In some cases, I would keep existing files and add another ones.
Do you know if it is possible to incremental deploy pages with gitlab ci?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public folder is not cleaned during each deployment.
However, most repositories do not actually have a public folder, it is instead created only dynamically during CI/CD. These dynamically created contents are not kept between deployments.

Simply store all files you want to keep between deployments in your repository. This can be in a folder called public in the root of your repository. This way, you will not have to move the files during CI/CD. Just make sure you do not overwrite/move/delete the files during within your `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration.

Of course, you can also store the files anywhere else in your repository and just move them to the right location under `public/` within your `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration.